# WSO Identity Server 5.1.0 - Importing Bulk Users with multiple Roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 Identity Server, is there a way to bulk import users with multiple roles?  Using the following method only gives the user the last specified role.

> UserName,Password,Claims
>   jdoe@test.org,password1,http://wso2.org/claims/lastname=Doe,http://wso2.org/claims/givenname=John,http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress=jdoe@test.org,http://wso2.org/claims/role=Application/TestApp1,http://wso2.org/claims/role=Application/TestApp1_Production
>   testuser@test.org,password1,http://wso2.org/claims/lastname=User,http://wso2.org/claims/givenname=Test,http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress=testuser@test.org,http://wso2.org/claims/role=Application/TestApp1,http://wso2.org/claims/role=Application/TestApp1_Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code [1] ,

This should be possible if you seperate your roles with ':'

ie. If you have your role claim in a format like 
http://wso2.org/claims/role=Application/TestApp1_Production:role2:role3

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/user-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/mgt/bulkimport/CSVUserBulkImport.java#L171

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!